# Linux: partial failure in rendering unicode special characters

Tags: unicode, terminal, raspberry-pi

Here is my starting point: Raspberry Pi 4, [Manjaro - Raspberry Pi 4 KDE Plasma](https://manjaro.org/downloads/arm/raspberry-pi-4/arm8-raspberry-pi-4-kde-plasma/)

Unicode special symbols fall into two big categories: the ones showing properly, and the ones displaying just boxes with some pips inside. The trouble is to be seen consistently in Konsole, LXTerminal, and in the i3 status line.

For example (Python, console output):

```python
print("\U0001F53B \U0001f321 \U00002728")
```

Just `\U0001f321` ("Thermometer") is rendered successfully. I tried different fonts, including [Nerd] *DejaVu Sans Mono*; nothing seems to make any difference.

It beats me guessing what is the visual difference between the two classes of characters. Certainly none of the wide and colorful is successful :)

UPD:

The `noto-fonts` and `noto-fonts-emoji` packages are of the essence. [Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/132086/partial-success-in-displaying-unicode-characters)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't really a programming problem. It should be on [the Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Terminals are not designed to support Unicode in a wide sense. There is Unicode support for characters on BMP (Basic Multilanguage Plan), but also in this case, with many limitation (e.g. one code point per cell, so without combining the combining characters). Just do no do this (possibly for next 5 or 10 years, or just volunteer to add such support). Just write to a file and display with other means (e.g. browser)

Comment: Essentially the same setup on an ordinary big box runs trouble free, Giacomo. I'd like to pinpoint the difference.

Comment: Note, you should tag me with @ to answer at me. For you (as questioner, or ev. as answerer) it is automatic. What do you man big box? Apple Terminal sucks, so programmers use iTerm2. Windows power shell still do not know Unicode (and in mangle data). Just that terminals are not a sexy area to work and most terminals are just forks of old terminals with cosmetic (interface) adjustment, but not real development. In fact we have trouble to select a good TERM.

Comment: I mean, the same Manjaro KDE Plasma on x86_64 platform. Raspberry Pi 4 is ARM.